# Commutator of $p$ and $x^n$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, commutator

I found this calculation about the commutator $[p, x^n]$:

$$\begin{aligned}\left[p, x^{n}\right] &=p x^{n}-x^{n} p \\ &=(p x) x^{n-1}-x^{n} p \\ &=x p x^{n-1}+[p, x] x^{n-1}-x^{n} p \\ &=x(p x) x^{n-2}+[p, x] x^{n-1}-x^{n} p \\ &=x^{2} p x^{n-2}+x[p, x] x^{n-2}+[p, x] x^{n-1}-x^{n} p \\ &=x^{2} p x^{n-2}+2[p, x] x^{n-1}-x^{n} p \\ &=x^{3} p x^{n-3}+3[p, x] x^{n-1}-x^{n} p \\ &=x^{n} p+n[p, x] x^{n-1}-x^{n} p \\ &=n[p, x] x^{n-1}=n \frac{\hbar}{i} x^{n-1} \end{aligned}$$

In lines 4 to 5, it seems like they take an $x$ from $px$ and move it to the left to make $x \cdot x = x^2$. Is that legal? Wouldn't that mean that $x$ and $p$ commute and we know they don't? Or what am I missing?

Comment: Your question was already answered below, I just want to point out that the equality can also be proved quite easily using mathematical induction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That isn't what happened in line 4 to 5.  The *px* in line 4 is replaced by *xp + [p,x]*
(because *px - xp = [p,x]*) and results in the additional term to the right of the first term.  This is a very common gambit in dealing with commutators.  It is the only "legal" way to switch the order of non-commuting operators. Like this:

$$ \begin{equation} line 4.5 = x(xp + [p,x])x^{n-2} + etc. \end{equation}  $$
$$ \begin{equation} line 4.7 = x(xp)x^{n-2} + x[p,x]x^{n-2} + etc. \end{equation} $$

They just skipped a few steps.